# Ubuntu installation stuck on detecting file systems

Tags: partitioning, unetbootin

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS onto an external hard drive. I used unetbootin. I’ve manually partitioned my disk to have 4000mb for swap, 20gb for / and about 300gb for /home.

My installation is just stuck on detecting file systems. It keeps saying

```
org.freedesktop.IBus.session.GNOME.service: Failed with result ‘timeout’
```

And this just repeats and repeats.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! 20GB for `/` will not be enough. This should be closer to 30 or 40 to handle all the snaps. Manual partitioning such as this is also *generally* not required as the defaults offered by the Ubuntu installer are sufficient for 99% of use cases. With regards to the issue itself, you may want to double-check that the `.iso` you downloaded is complete. This particular issue can be seen if the installation media is built from an incomplete image 

Comment: 0. I agree with matigo (tell us if you need help to check the iso file); 1. Please tell us details about your computer: Brand name and model of the computer itself and about the graphics chip (also brand name and model) and about the wifi (also brand name and model); 2. Is it Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? 3. You can try another tool/method to install Ubuntu (depending on which operating system is running in the computer where you create the USB boot drive: Ubuntu, other Linux, Windows, MacOS); 4. You can remove the partition table in the target hard drive before starting the installer.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for the reply. My computer is a Surface Laptop 2 with Intel UHD Graphics and Marvell AVASTAR Network. It is Ubuntu Desktop. I have data on my hard drive which I wish to keep. I am also not sure how to check that the .iso is complete, so any help would be appreciated. Would this issue have anything to do with me being on school wifi? I have downloaded the certificate needed, maybe the school firewall is blocking something?

Comment: It should work to install without connection to the internet, so I don't think that is a problem. Intel graphics should work with Ubuntu. I don't know the Marwell network hardware. I assume that you use Windows. If you use Rufus in dd-mode or Balena Etcher (which are cloning tools) you can [check first the iso file](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview), and then  [compare it with the content of the USB drive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&p=14142910#post14142910) and make sure things are good.

Comment: @sudodus Hi, I’ve reinstalled the iso and verified the file. The original issue seems to be gone but now it’s been a around 20-30 minutes of the installer detecting file systems. It’s saying warning: source id… was not found when attempting to remove it. It keeps doing this with different source ids. Is this normal?

Comment: I’m using an external hard drive instead of a usb stick, could that be the problem? I’m installing Ubuntu on the same hard drive.

Comment: If the computer is too weak it happens that the installation of Ubuntu is timed out (too slow to be accepted). How old is the computer? You have not told us about the version of CPU and the amount of RAM. This may or may not be the problem. - If it is the problem, you might have better luck with a light-weight community flavour, Lubuntu or Xubuntu (the same version 22.04.2 LTS).

Comment: @sudodus I seem to have fixed the original issue by just going out and buying a usb stick. But now after I install with manual partition, I get booted in a Grub terminal. I’m doing 8gb of swap, 40gb of / and 300gb of /home. Am I doing it wrong? I’ve check the iso install. Is there another way to install Ubuntu without wiping my external hard drive?

Comment: Yes, there are many different ways to install Ubuntu successfully. Some are ways easier, some more difficult. It is more straightforward to let the installer select what to do without forcing it to something, that it should accept and fix, but maybe not quite manage. And that will be done with a blank target device.